# Cannot use ssh keys anymore to connect with different services or repositories

Tags: server, ssh, openssh

I set a bunch of keys that I use for various reasons like connecting to my personal website or various source control management platforms like GitHub or sourcehut. I was working as usually as recently as yesterday, but today suddenly none of my keys worked when I tried to connect with ssh. When I try to connect it just for example to my website it shows this screen:

```
# ssh -vvv -i ~/.ssh/digitalocean_ed25519 name@mywebsite.com
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.2, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "mywebsite.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to mywebsite.com [mywebsiteip] port 22.
debug1: connect to address mywebsiteip port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host mywebsite.com port 22: Connection timed out
```

Same thing happens when I try to clone a read/write repository for source management websites like github or sourcehut.

From another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62011181/how-to-point-ssh-to-config-file) it suggests to look the permissions, but they appear to be ok. And I didn't had a config file.

```
ls -l
total 36
-rw------- 1 user user  464 Jul 17 09:41 digitalocean_ed25519
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  104 Apr 12 20:55 digitalocean_ed25519.pub
-rw------- 1 user user  464 Apr 12 17:02 github_ed25519
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  104 Apr 12 17:02 github_ed25519.pub
-rw------- 1 user user  419 Apr 17 23:11 gitlab_ed25519
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  104 Apr 17 23:11 gitlab_ed25519.pub
-rw------- 1 user user 1998 Jun  1 21:59 known_hosts
-rw------- 1 user user 2655 Apr 12 19:44 srht_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  566 Apr 12 19:44 srht_rsa.pub
```

and `.ssh` folder has 700 permission.
I reinstalled ssh `sudo apt install openssh-server` but to no avail. Problem persists even after reinstalling. Only thing I did I deleted in the .ssh folder is the file `known_hosts.old`, but I think it has nothing to do to my problem. I suspect the key management system of Ubuntu 20.04 is to blame, but I am not sure.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you running? Have the file permissions in your `.ssh` directory recently changed? 

Comment: Since the other end is timing out, check the server logs.

Comment: Check your output: `connection timed out` is not an ssh authentication error. It suggests a network problem at the server end.

Comment: @waltinator I think the problem is on my part . My public keys are in the remote server as they should be https://github.com/username.keys, https://gitlab.com/username.keys, or https://meta.sr.ht/keys .

Comment: Read `man ssh-add` and start with `ssh-add -l`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

I am sorry for wasting everyone's time. My ISP was to blame because it updated my modem, changed my password and blocked port 22 for 'security' reasons. I wasted two days about this problem, changing my configurations, trying different ports, resetting my router just because ISP didn't even bother to sent me a notice. Thank you for your answers.